# Rails URL and Path Helpers in Engines Like Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, rails-routing

I'm trying to use some URL and/or path helpers in my Rails 4 Engine views such as resource_url or resource_path. These engines are configured a bit differently than the typical --mountable tutorial out there. In fact, they more closely resemble how Spree does it, without the Spree::ENGINE_NAME namespace.

Like Spree's architecture, I'm attempting to create **core** engine that my other engines depend on. For example, my **backend** engine's `routes.rb` file looks like this:

```
Core::Engine.add_routes do

    # Check to see if the request comes in on a subdomain
    # The Subdomains class passed into constraints()
    # is a class defined in lib/subdomain.rb
    constraints(Subdomain) do
      match '/manage' => "manage#index", :via => [:get]
    end

end
```

In a view inside my **backend** engine, I'd like to be able to use some URL/path helpers to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to manage_path, manage_path %>
```

This doesn't work, because I'm drawing the routes on the **core** engine. So, I must use

```
<%= link_to core_engine.manage_path, core_engine.manage_path %>
```

Spree somehow gets around this, but I'm not sure how. For example, in [`backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/index.html.erb`](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/f89d5c5c77808eb7dc2f4570719d8ceecfa3ce08/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/index.html.erb):

```
<%= link_to product.try(:name), edit_admin_product_path(product) %>
```

Notice, the `edit_admin_product_path`, but no mention of this actually being drawn on the **core** engine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

We get around this by drawing all the routes on the core engine using `add_routes` which exists for reasons I won't go into here because it's a long tangent. Necessary evil for this kind of work, though.

The `isolate_namespace` method within `Core::Engine` scopes everything to the `spree` namespace. If you're inside a controller that's been drawn underneath the `Spree::Core::Engine` routes and you want to reference a route for another controller also drawn under that route then you can leave off the `spree.` prefix on the routing helper.

If you're routing to a different engine, then you will need to have the prefix: `main_app.` or whatever.

The [Engines Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) explains this in greater detail, and I'd recommend reading that.